# Circular motion with a radius within a circle

Tags: java, android, animation

For two days I have a math problem I'm trying to solve.
I created a circle with the drawCircle function.
I drew a radius in the circle.
Now I wanted to make a circular animation of the radius (only the radius) at the circle. As the rendering below.
[image]

```
public class radar extends Fragment {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


private class theRadar extends View{

    public theRadar(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);

        DashPathEffect dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{5,5}, (float)1.0);
        p.setPathEffect(dashPath);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        p.setStrokeWidth(8f);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth()/2, p);

        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        canvas.drawLine(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, 20, getWidth()/2, p);

        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View theRadar = new theRadar(getActivity());
    return theRadar;
}
```

}

Thanks for your help

Comment: "circular scan" what is is?

Comment: My english is not very good sorry it means circular animation. like radar scanning !

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I think I have to update for each call the stopX and stopY of the function drawLine in order to have a rotation motion for my Line. But the problem is how to get all the coordinates of the my circle

Comment: for coordinates see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations), use "parametric form"

Comment: I am gonna have a look of this and get back to you ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you @pskink for you suggestion !
I solved my problem thanks to your link ! 
For those who have the same problem I put the code

a and b : centre coordinates of circle (a, b)

r : The radius in pixels

tcur : the angle of the radius

```
tcur = tcur + Math.toRadians(2);
x = (int) (a +r*Math.cos(tcur));
y = (int) (b +r*Math.sin(tcur));

canvas.drawLine(a, b, x, y, p);
```